# javascript regex to replace anchor tag of specific class with text

Tags: jquery, anchor

I have a HTML text, I want to replace anchor tag of the specific class with text in jquery.

For example,

```
var htmltext="test message <a class="red pagtag" href="#" contenteditable="false">Harshvardhan Rane</a> test <br> <a class="red pagtag" href="#" contenteditable="false">Jay Alvarrez</a>";
```

I want to replace whole anchor tag with text.

Required output:

```
var htmltext="test message **Harshvardhan Rane** test <br> **Jay Alvarrez**";
```

Comment: So in other words you want to remove the `<a>` elements from the string, is that correct?

Comment: Yes.I want to replace <a> tag with other text.

Answer (score 3):

It is never a good idea to change HTML with regex.
Instead, since you mention jQuery, use the node manipulation tools:

```js
var htmltext='test message <a class="red pagtag" href="#" contenteditable="false">Harshvardhan Rane</a> test <br> <a class="red pagtag" href="#" contenteditable="false">Jay Alvarrez</a>';
var $html = $("<div/>").html(htmltext);
$html.find("a").each(function() {
  $(this).replaceWith("**"+$(this).text()+"**");
});
$("body").append($html)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try use method `replace` with the next regular expression:

```
htmltext.replace(/<\/*a.*?>/g,'**')
```

This statement should return exact what you need.

```js
var htmltext='test message <a class="red pagtag" href="#" contenteditable="false">Harshvardhan Rane</a> test <br> <a class="red pagtag" href="#" contenteditable="false">Jay Alvarrez</a>';

htmltext=htmltext.replace(/<\/*a.*?>/g,'**');
console.log(htmltext);
```

Comment: And it does. I still prefer to manipulate the tags using DOM or in this case jQuery